# Uneven microstepping movement

Tags: stepper-motor, stepper-driver

I'm trying to control a stepper motor with an Allegro A4988 driver with microstepping.

When advancing a few steps with no load, I can see that at full-step mode all steps have equal angle, but in half-step mode there are large differences. At quarter-step I can tell some steps have zero angle, i.e. stepping doesn't move the axle at all. But I'd need my motors to move evenly at 16th-steps.

I've tuned the current control so that the winding current in full-step mode is at 70% of rated current.

I have no datasheet for the motor: I recovered it from some old dot-matrix printers built in the 80s-90s. It has 48 steps and 50ohm coil resistance. It's an unipolar stepper with 6 wires, and I'm using it as bipolar by leaving the two center wires disconnected. Given that the printer would originally be powered at 12V and the coils are connected in series, I assume a maximum current of 120mA so I based my tuning on that.

I'm powering the drivers with a bench power supply, set to 12V and max current 1A. It also powers a Raspberry Pi through a step-down converter; when motors are off the supply shows 210mA, and 310-330mA when on and stepping.

I tried other steppers taken from other printers, hard drives and floppy drives roughly the same age, and they all behave the same. I tried other [A4988 modules](https://www.electrodragon.com/product/stepstick-stepper-driver-board-a4988-v2/) in the same batch, and the results are the same.

I have no "modern" steppers so I wonder if the stepper age is a problem, but on the other hand it's weird that they all show the same behavior.

Comment: It probably depends how "sticky" the load is. It may even need a steady mechanical load (friction pad) to stop one step overshooting (which means no motion on the next step)

Comment: This happens both without load (actually with a small gear on the shaft I can't detach) and with a load (by holding the shaft with my fingers and let the motor move itself).
Is it possible that those motors simply aren't suitable for microstepping?